# Count the number of instances of value AFTER sql query in php

Tags: php, sql-server

I have been working on this for some time.
I query the database for the information below.

I then want to count the values (Servicepack 3, 2 and 1) and assign each count number to a individual variable.  i would prefer not to do separate sql queries or count using the sql query.

Thanks

```
//-----------------------------------------------
// Perform operations with connection.
//-----------------------------------------------

$sql = "SELECT Name, DomainName, OperatingSystem, ServicePack FROM Computers";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );

// Check for 0 results

if( $stmt === false) {
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
```

Comment: doing the count in the query is what you should be doing - what do you have against it?

Comment: It is not so clear what you exactly want and why you want it this way. Could you please clear that up?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count it all with php you can do it like this.. (after your code)

```
$counts = array(
    'Servicepack 3' => 0,
    'Servicepack 2' => 0,
    'Servicepack 1' => 0,
);
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if (isset($counts[$row['ServicePack']])) {
        ++$counts[$row['ServicePack']];
    }
}
```

But you know you can do this with a group by in with SQL.. something like..

`$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS ServicePackCounts, OperatingSystem, ServicePack FROM Computers GROUP BY OperatingSystem, ServicePack";`

Comment: Yup. Databases are optimized for these kind of stuff. So a group by is better.

Comment: Sorry; if I was not clear.  I was trying not to make my question to complicated... :)

Comment: I am passing a variable from a form to a proccess.php page that will be used in my SQL query.  (This is not working out either.. :()  But the original use of the question above is; i want to take the count and use it as a variable in one of my other pages - passed as a session.  Hope that helps clear some things up.